# stream mp3 files on user's alexa device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an Android app that plays mp3 files that I host online, I want to give the users an option to stream mp3 file from my app to their own Alexa devices by using the mp3 link; so is that possible and what is the best approach to achieve it? and where to start?

Answer (score 0):

The radio skill will be implemented using AudioPlayer interface, please find more information on the link below:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html .

There is an AudioPlayer sample skill which actually streams from a radio station already to which you can refer. That can be found here: https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

You will need to change the url stream and add your own. Please take into account that the URL you provide in the audioItem.stream.url property must meet these requirements:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements

Also you can use the Alexa Radio Skills Kit (RSK). With the Alexa Radio Skills Kit. RSK allows providers to enable a high-quality customer experience in a no-code way, so that listeners can seamlessly access their radio station on Alexa just by using their voice. All providers have to do is submit their station data, and Alexa Radio Skills Kit Console handles subsequent steps related to publishing and discovery.

More information can be found here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2023/04/alexa-skills-radio-kit-march

Link for the console:
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/radio-skills-kit/index.html